# How to force drop database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to force drop a database, but after dropping the database, when I try to recreate the database, I'm getting the error

> cannot create file C:\Program Files.....[databasename].mdf because it already exists

Here's my query to force drop the database

```
Use master;
ALTER database [databasename] set offline with ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP database [databasename];
```

I understood that, the above query is dropping the database, but it's not deleting the `.ldf` and `.mdf` files. How to drop the database thoroughly?

A normal query

```
Drop database [databasename] ; //deletes the database completely, including the ldf and mdf's.
```

How to force drop a database, which also deletes the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

That is expected and [**documented** behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx):

> *Dropping a database deletes the database from an instance of SQL Server and deletes the physical disk files used by the database. **If the database or any one of its files is offline when it is dropped, the disk files are not deleted.** These files can be deleted manually by using Windows Explorer. To remove a database from the current server without deleting the files from the file system, use sp_detach_db.*

So why are you taking your database offline first? Just set it into `SINGLE_USER` mode and then drop it as documented on SQL Server Books Online.-

```
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE [databasename] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE [databasename] ;
```

Note, database backups will *not* be deleted as part of the process documented above.

Comment: This won't work because you are not the current user who uses the DB, if any other process keeps trying to connect to it it won't work.